# How to set markers with errorbars in different colours?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, markers, errorbar

How to:

- display symbols in the legend
- colour markers in the same way as the errorbars (argument color gives an error: ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4
- remove connecting lines - get only the scatter with errorbars

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  # for legend handle

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))

times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rvs = [2, 4, 2, 4, 7]
sigma = [0.564, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4]
rv_telescopes = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']

d = {'rv_times': times, 'rv_rvs': rvs, 'rv_sigma': sigma, 'rv_telescopes': rv_telescopes }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

colors = {'A':'#008f00', 'B':'#e36500', 'C':'red'}

plt.errorbar(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], df['rv_sigma'], marker = '_', ecolor = df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors), color = df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors), zorder = 1, ms = 30)


handles = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='_', color='w', markerfacecolor=v, label=k, markersize=10) for k, v in colors.items()]

ax.legend(handles=handles, loc='upper left', ncol = 2, fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

**After edit**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  # for legend handle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rvs = [2, 4, 2, 4, 7]
sigma = [0.564, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4]
rv_telescopes = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']

d = {'rv_times': times, 'rv_rvs': rvs, 'rv_sigma': sigma, 'rv_telescopes': rv_telescopes}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
colors = {'A': '#008f00', 'B': '#e36500', 'C': 'red'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.errorbar(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], df['rv_sigma'], color='none', ecolor=df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors) ,linewidth=1)
ax.scatter(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], marker='_', linewidth=3, color=df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors), s=1000)

for rv_teles in np.unique(df['rv_telescopes']):
     color = colors[rv_teles]
     df1 = df[df['rv_telescopes'] == rv_teles]  # filter out rows corresponding to df['rv_telescopes']
     ax.errorbar(df1['rv_times'], df1['rv_rvs'], df1['rv_sigma'],
                 color=color, ls='', marker='_', ms=30, linewidth=3, label=rv_teles)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=1, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.errorbar()` works very similar to `plt.plot()` with extra parameters. As such, it primarily draws a line graph, using a single color. The error bars can be given individual colors via the `ecolor=` parameter. The markers, however, get the same color as the line graph. The line graph can be suppressed via an empty `linestyle`. On top of that, `plt.scatter()` can draw markers with individual colors.

In order not the mix the ['object-oriented'](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) with the 'functional interface', the following example code uses `ax.errorbar()` and `ax.scatter()`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  # for legend handle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
rvs = [2, 4, 2, 4, 7]
sigma = [0.564, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4]
rv_telescopes = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']

d = {'rv_times': times, 'rv_rvs': rvs, 'rv_sigma': sigma, 'rv_telescopes': rv_telescopes}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
colors = {'A': '#008f00', 'B': '#e36500', 'C': 'red'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.errorbar(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], df['rv_sigma'], color='none', ecolor=df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors))
ax.scatter(df['rv_times'], df['rv_rvs'], marker='_', color=df['rv_telescopes'].map(colors), s=100)

handles = [Line2D([0], [0], linestyle='', marker='_', color=v, label=k, markersize=10) for k, v in colors.items()]
ax.legend(handles=handles, loc='upper left', ncol=1, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image: error bars with individual colors]

A far easier approach would be to call `ax.errorbar()` multiple times, once for each color. This would automatically create appropriate legend handles:

```py
for rv_teles in np.unique(df['rv_telescopes']):
     color = colors[rv_teles]
     df1 = df[df['rv_telescopes'] == rv_teles]  # filter out rows corresponding to df['rv_telescopes']
     ax.errorbar(df1['rv_times'], df1['rv_rvs'], df1['rv_sigma'],
                 color=color, ls='', marker='_', ms=30, label=rv_teles)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncol=1, fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image: calling ax.errorbar once for each color]

Comment: Thank you very much. How to do the reverse case, please? I mean markers lw = 3 and errorbars lw = 1.

Comment: You can use `mew` for the linewidth of the markers. So, e.g. `ax.errorbar(df1['rv_times'], df1['rv_rvs'], df1['rv_sigma'],color=color, lw=1, ls='', marker='_', ms=30, mew=3, label=rv_teles)`